# Converting a list of letters into a word (and removing speech marks)

Tags: list, haskell, output

Does anyone know of a way in Haskell to convert something in the form

```
["w","o","r","d"]
```

into

```
word
```

I have just finished my very first program (an RSA encryption) and the output at the moment is really ugly. I'm sorry if this is a really silly question but I really have no idea of how to go about it. Also, to make my input a lot easier, does anyone know of a way to convert

```
word
```

into

```
[w,o,r,d]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even if you've never heard of "concat", here's how you can solve this type of problem. Let's figure out what type you have:

```
λ> :t ["w","o","r","d"]
["w","o","r","d"] :: [[Char]]
```

OK, so that's a list of lists of `Char`s.

Now let's figure out the type you want:

```
λ> :t "word"
"word" :: [Char]
```

So we want a function that converts list of lists of `Char`s to simple lists of `Char`s. In other words, we want a function with the signature `[[Char]] -> [Char]`. Let's search for a function with that type signature* using [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%5B%5BChar%5D%5D%20-%3E%20%5BChar%5D). Doing that just now, the fourth function in the list was:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
base Prelude, base Data.List
Concatenate a list of lists.
```

That's exactly what we want.

- Better yet, you might have realised that the operation we need could operate with lists of any type. Then you would search for the type signature `[[a]] -> [a]`. (This sort of insight comes with practice.) When I did that just now, `concat` was the first result.

Comment: I can't vote up your reply because my reputation isn't high enough but thank you very much, I'll have a go at applying this now.

Comment: This is probably a really stupid question but how do I now apply the operation that you've given me?

Comment: Just the fact that you mentioned Hoogle makes this reply a lot better than the others. Hoogle is an invaluable tool when you are working with Haskell!

Answer (score 5):

Check the types:

```
Prelude> let s = ["w","o","r","d"]
Prelude> :t s
s :: [[Char]]
```

So you can treat it as a list of lists of characters.

What function "flattens" lists? concat:

```
Prelude> :t concat s
concat s :: [Char]
```

So that's our string, and we print it with putStrLn

```
Prelude> putStrLn  $ concat s
word
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, `concat` is the way to go for converting a `[[Char]]` into `[Char]`, as for going the other way, you have two options.  You can treat your string `"word"` as the list of `Char`s it is (remember, it's type is `String`, which is just an alias for `[Char]`) and just operate on `Char`s instead of `String`s, or you can convert each single character into a single-character `String`.  I recommend the former, but I'll demonstrate the other as well.

The easiest way to do this is with a very simple list comprehension.  All you have to do is get each letter from the word, and wrap it in `[]` to make it a list.  Since `String = [Char]`, you get each letter of the word as a `String`.

```
splitUpWord :: String -> [String]
splitUpWord word = [[letter] | letter <- word]
```

Comment: Thanks, my reputation isn't high enough to vote up your answer but I'll have a go at this after I've sorted the first part of my question :)

Comment: Another (more idiomatic) way of doing it would be `splitUpWord = map (:[])`.

Comment: @kqr That was my first solution, but I was going for clarity for user2710971's sake.

Answer (score 1):

Look at concat. You have a list of lists of chars. Flattening this is a common pattern and concat is the tool to do it. That said, if you're learning you might give it a go yourself.